# Saturated models and definable substructures

Tags: model-theory

Let $M$ be a saturated model of a theory $T$ in a first-order language $\mathcal{L}$, and let $N$ be a submodel of $M$.

Is it possible to have a substructure $A\neq N$ of $M$ such that $N \subset A \subset M$ and every element of $A$ is definable by a formula in $L$ with parameters from $N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $T$ be the theory of an endless discrete order, which is a complete theory. Let $M=\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{Q}$ consist of $\mathbb{Q}$ copies of the $\mathbb{Z}$ order, which is a countable saturated model of $T$, and let $N$ consist of only the even elements in each copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, which still forms a model of $T$ (though not an elementary substructure of $M$), with $A$ adding in some or all of the odd elements. Each of these new elements in $A$ is definable in $M$ from their immediate predecessors, which are in $N$.

Comment: Wouldn't it work with taking any $N$ which is not an elementary submodel, and considering $A$ to be the elementary submodel generated by $N$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The non-elementary submodels must miss some elements in one of their $\mathbb{Z}$ chains, and then $A$ would fill in those missing elements, which would be definable from the other elements of that $\mathbb{Z}$ chain.

Comment: (I was actually talking about arbitrary languages and models, not just this one. For example $\Bbb N$ with $\leq$ and $\Bbb N\setminus\{6\}$ with $\leq$.)

Comment: Well, in general there might not be "the" elementary submodel generated by a given submodel, unless you have definable Skolem functions, which are not always available. But when they are, as here, then yes, that is what is going on with this example.

Comment: For example, consider DLO and $\mathbb{Z}$ sitting inside $\mathbb{Q}$. This is not an elementary substructure, but we cannot add any new points definably from integers.

Comment: Ah, good point about the definable Skolem functions, I didn't think about that. Thanks!